# Generate XSD schemas from an existing database or JPA entities

Tags: java, maven, jpa, xsd, hyperjaxb

I have been using hyperjaxb tool to generate JPA entities and database scripts from XSD schemas. Now I want basically the inverse operation. How can I generate XSD schemas based on JPA anotated entities or database? I am using Maven, so any maven solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA, see the following link:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generate-xml-schema-from-java-using-jaxb-dialog.html

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA, so this option worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This maven plugin ( jaxb2-maven-plugin ) might be useful for you.
This post has more information about its usage and the given example uses POJO's to do the transformation

[Generate XSD from Java class](http://www.journaldev.com/1316/how-to-generate-xsd-from-java-class)

Comment: According to that, I have to annotate my Java classes with JAXB annotations. Is there a way to not to be forced to do that?

Comment: I believe that you need the JAXB annotations. Another option is to use schemagen.exe on the command line ( found within the Java JDK\bin directory)  to create the XSD files

Comment: [Link to the Oracle document ] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/schemagen.html